# How to define a function of parent class using inheritance?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have made the member functions of the parent class public. But still I get an error

> no 'void MotorBike::speeddown()' member function declared in class 'MotorBike'

both for `speedup` and `speeddown`. Even though I have publicly inherited the parent class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class Bicycle
{
protected:
    int speed;
    char color[8];
public:
    Bicycle(int, char*);
    void speedup();
    void speeddown();
    void turnLeft();
    void turnRight();
};

class MotorBike:public Bicycle
{
private:
    int currentGear;
    int currentFuel;
public:
    MotorBike(int,char*,int,int);

};

Bicycle::Bicycle(int Speed,char* Color)
{
    speed=Speed;
    strcpy(color,Color);
    cout<<"The bike is now moving north!"<<endl;
}

MotorBike::MotorBike(int Speed,char* Color,int CurrentGear,int CurrentFuel): Bicycle(speed,color)
{
    speed=Speed;
    strcpy(color,Color);
    currentGear=CurrentGear;
    currentFuel=CurrentFuel;
    cout<<"The motorbike is now moving north!"<<endl;
}

void Bicycle::speedup()//error line
{
    cout<<"Speed is increased!"<<endl;
    speed+=1;
}

void Bicycle::speeddown()//error line
{
    if(speed>1)
    {
        cout<<"Speed is decreased!"<<endl;
        speed-=1;
    }
    else
        cout<<"The bike is already at rest!"<<endl;

}

void MotorBike::speedup()//error line
{
    if(currentGear==4)
        cout<<"You are already at maximum speed!"<<endl;
    else
    {
        switch(currentGear)
        {
        case 0:
            currentGear=1;
            currentFuel-=0.01;
            speed+=0.25;
            break;
        case 1:
            currentGear=2;
            currentFuel-=0.02;
            speed+=0.5;
            break;
        case 2:
            currentGear=3;
            currentFuel-=0.03;
            speed+=0.75;
            break;
        case 3:
            currentGear=4;
            currentFuel-=0.04;
            speed+=1;
            break;

        }
    }
}

void MotorBike::speeddown()//error line
{
    if(speed==1||speed>1)
    speed-=1;
    else
        cout<<"You are already at minimum speed!"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Bicycle B1(0,"Black");
    MotorBike MB1(0,"Black",0,100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MotorBike` doesn't have a function `speedup` nor `speeddown`. If you want want, you have to declare it in the `MotorBike` class, like

```
class MotorBike:public Bicycle
{
private:
    int currentGear;
    int currentFuel;
public:
    MotorBike(int,char*,int,int);
    void speedup();
    void speeddown();
};
```

Comment: but my bicycle have them and i have inherited them from bicycle.

Comment: @AhmadShafique, true - but you already inherited the definition as well. If you want to provide a different definition for descendent class, you need to **override** them.

Comment: Inheriting them means you get the original implementation. What you are trying to do is override them, in which case you have to declare this intent in the class definition, as @SergeyA says.

Comment: @AhmadShafique, and while you are on it, consider using `override` keyword.

Comment: @SergeyA Isn't that only for `virtual` functions?

Comment: @NathanOliver, it is indeed. But that is something to get OP thinking :) It is very rare when you need to override a non-virtual function (outside of CRTP).

Answer (score -1):

I'm just going to go top-to-bottom on this one:

Change your deprecated `#include <string.h>` to `#include <string>`.

Your Bicycle has functions with no definition, which will yield LNK2019 (unresolved externals) if something tries to call them. Either define them, remove them, or make Bicycle an abstract class.  Bicycle has children too, so give it a virtual destructor.

```
Bicycle(int, char*);
virtual ~Bicycle() = default;
virtual void speedup();
virtual void speeddown();
virtual void turnLeft();
virtual void turnRight();
```

You're defining functions that are members of MotorBike, but you never declared them. Add them to the declaration of MotorBike:

```
class MotorBike:public Bicycle
{
private:
    int currentGear;
    int currentFuel;
public:
    Motorbike(int,char*,int,int);
    void speedup();
    void speeddown();
};
```

Use the `override` keyword when overriding Bicycle functions in MotorBike:

```
class MotorBike:public Bicycle
{
private:
    int currentGear;
    int currentFuel;
public:
    Motorbike(int,char*,int,int);
    void speedup() override;  // like this
    void speeddown() override;  // and this
};
```

Or, alternatively, use any default functions implemented by Bicycle in MotorBike:

```
class MotorBike:public Bicycle
{
private:
    int currentGear;
    int currentFuel;
public:
    Motorbike(int,char*,int,int);
    using Bicycle::speedup;  // like this
    using Bicycle::speeddown;  // and this
};
```

Fix your data types. MotorBike declares `currentGear` and `currentFuel` as integers, but in `MotorBike::speedup`, for example, you're adding floating-point values to them. This won't work, because the fractional portions of these values will be truncated.